# Separate chapters, each with individual preface, included in same document

Tags: sectioning, include, subfiles

I have a document I want to split up into individual sections.  I'd like each individual section to be independently compilable, but of course I also need the whole document to compile.

The trouble is, each of my individual sections requires a large preface (`\usepackage` calls, command definitions, etc.) that I am including with either `\input` or `\include`.  The preface includes the `\documentclass` command, so I end up getting `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` if I try to compile the whole document.

I'm already using `\usepackage{subfiles}`, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: The best package for this is [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) and class. It works great for me. I you might want to collect all your packages and preamble into a separate file so that this file can be included both in the main document and the sub documents.  There are numerous examples on this site.

Comment: @PeterGrill make that an answer, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best package for this is [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) and class.  There are numerous examples on this site.

You might want to collect all your packages and preamble into a separate file so that this file can be included both in the main document and the sub documents.